# Pass list of different named tuples to different csv by tuple name

Tags: python, csv, namedtuple

I have a program in which I wish to record all major changes that occur. For example: each time a variable x changes in value record the time of the change and the change itself. Within the program there are many such changes and not all have the same number of parameters.

I decided to use namedtuples to store each instance of a change and to then put those namedtuples into a single master data list -ready for export to csv. I have used tuples as of course they are immutable which is ideal for record keeping. Below I have tried to explain in as concise a manner as possible what I have done and tried. Hopefully my problem and attempts so far are clear.

So I have:

```
data = []
```

as the main repository, with namedtuples of the form:

```
a_tuple = namedtuple('x_change', ['Time', 'Change'])
another_tuple = namedtuple('y_change', ['Time', 'Change', 'id'])
```

I can then append instances of these namedtuples each time a change is detected to data using commands as below:

```
data.append(a_tuple(a_time, a_change))
data.append(another_tuple(a_time, a_change, an_id))
```

If I then print out the contents of data I would get output like:

```
x_change(a_time=4, a_change=1)
y_change(a_time=5, a_change=3, an_id = 2)
y_change(a_time=7, a_change=1, an_id = 3)
x_change(a_time=8, a_change=3)
```

what I would like to do is export these tuples to csv files by tuple name. So in the above case I would end up with two csv files of the form:

```
name, time, change
x_change, 4, 1
x_change, 8, 3
```

and;

```
name, time, change, id
y_change, 5, 3, 2
y_change, 7, 1, 3
```

I have to date managed to write to a single csv as below:

```
with open ('events.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    output = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter = ',')
    for row in data:
        output.writerow(row)
```

which produces the output minus the tuple name. So:

```
4, 1
5, 3, 2
7, 1, 3
8, 3
```

I have also tried:

```
with open ('events.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    output = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter = ',')
    for row in data:
        output.writerow(str(row))
```

Which splits the file into csv format, including the tuple name, by every character getting (first line only included):

```
x, _, c, h, a, n, g, e, 4, 1
```

I have searched for a solution but not come across anything that fits what I am trying to do and am now at a loss. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following approach should work. This will take your data containing all of your named tuples and first sort it by the tuple's type. It then groups all of the entries and creates a CSV file for each. The first row in each CSV file contains the fields names:

```
from collections import namedtuple
from itertools import groupby
import csv

data = [] 

a_tuple = namedtuple('x_change', ['Time', 'Change'])
another_tuple = namedtuple('y_change', ['Time', 'Change', 'id'])

data.append(a_tuple(6, 1))
data.append(a_tuple(2, 1))
data.append(another_tuple(5, 3, 2))
data.append(another_tuple(7, 1, 3))
data.append(a_tuple(5, 2))

data.sort(key=lambda x: type(x).__name__)

for k, g in groupby(data, lambda x: type(x).__name__):
    with open('{}.csv'.format(k), 'w', newline='') as f_output:
        csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
        rows = list(g)
        csv_output.writerow(['Name'] + list(rows[0]._fields))
        for row in rows:
            csv_output.writerow([type(row).__name__] + list(row))
```

For my data, this would give you two CSV files as follows:

**x_change.csv**

```
Name,Time,Change
x_change,6,1
x_change,2,1
x_change,5,2
```

**y_change.csv**

```
Name,Time,Change,id
y_change,5,3,2
y_change,7,1,3
```

Comment: Just perfect! I now just need to figure out how what you did actually works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the `namedtuple` instance representation - `__repr__`.

```
>>>import namedtuple

>>>Row = namedtuple('Row', 'time, change')
>>>record = Row(4, 1)
```

...

```
>>>help(record)
class Row(builtins.tuple)
 |  Row(time, change)
 |
 |  Method resolution order:
 |      Row
 |      builtins.tuple
 |      builtins.object
 |
 |  Methods defined here:
 |
 |  __getnewargs__(self)
 |      Return self as a plain tuple.  Used by copy and pickle.
 |
 |  __getstate__(self)
 |      Exclude the OrderedDict from pickling
 |
 |  __repr__(self)
 |      Return a nicely formatted representation string
 |
 |  _asdict(self)
 |      Return a new OrderedDict which maps field names to their values.
 |
...


>>> record.__repr__()
'Row(time=4, change=1)'
>>> repr(record)
'Row(time=4, change=1)'
```

from there you may need to do a little bit of parsing but it is a good starting point since the `namedtuple` name is present.

Hope that this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could make your life easier by making the name a field in the `namedtuple`.

```
xChange = namedtuple('xChange', ['name', 'time' 'change'])
yChange = namedtuple('yChange', ['name', 'time', 'change', 'id'])
```

`namedtuple` doesn't have default values, but you could subclass xChange for example, to make a namedtuple that sets the name to 'x_change' in `__init__`

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you need to accomplish:

1. getting the name of the type into the row
2. creating one file per tuple type

For #1, create a function to return the row you really want.

```
def get_row_output(row):
    return [type(row).__name__] + list(row)
```

(Named tuples end up creating a custom type named with the value of the first parameter to `namedtuple()`. That name won't make it into any representation of the data of an instance of that type, so you have to extract it yourself.)

For #2, to end up with different files, you will need to loop over data outside the code that writes out the CSVs. The simplest approach:

```
for row in data:
    with open(row.__name__ + '.csv', 'a+') as csvfile:
        output = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        output.writerow(get_row_output(row))
```

(Note opening the file in append mode, as you're opening and closing files on each row.)

If `data` is very large, then you may be better off keeping the file handles open instead of opening and closing for each row. Something like:

```
def get_filename(row):
    return row.__name__ + '.csv'

def write_changes(data):
    file_handles = {}
    csv_writers = {}

    for row in data:
        filename = get_filename(row)
        if filename not in file_handles:
            f = open(filename, 'wb')
            file_handles[filename] = f
            csv_writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
            csv_writers[filename] = csv_writer

        csv_writers[filename].writerow(get_row_output(row))

    for f in file_handles.values():
        f.close()
```